# 4 bit subtractor using 2's complement of an adder

Tags: adder

currently having problem with my carry in to carry out.

i have used this for my LSB 
    assign S=A^(~B+1)^Cin;
    assign COUT=(A&~B)|((CIN+1)&(A^~B));

and this for my 3 higher bits.
    assign S=A^~B^Cin;
    assign Cout=(A&~B)|(Cin&(A^~B));

[image: full adder circuit. But will need to add a 2's complement subtractor.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RYour expressions for individual bits shouldn't use the term "B+1", that can have three possible values (0,1,2) and require two bits to express.

Your expressions for all 4 bits of the adder should be the same:

Sn    = An^~Bn^Cin;
Coutn = (An&~Bn)|(Cin&(An^~Bn));

Where 'n' represents the bit number.

The Cin for the entire adder should be set to a 1 to do the complement + 1 function.

Try this approach to thinking about it:

Forget about A for the moment.  How would you create the 2's complement of B with your logic?

You would put the complement of B into the 4 input lines of the adder, then to add the 1 you would set the carry in.  This should result in the 2's complement of B at the output.

Now add A into the other 4 input pins.  You should get the A-B at the output.  The carry output is then used as an overflow status bit that tells you about the relative magnitude of the two operands.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response! But isn't Cin just a variable. and may i know why does it have to be set to 1? In the case here, Cin is a carry input and by setting it to 1, won't it deem it wrong? correct me please!

Comment: Not for the LSB.  You have specific case of doing A-B; there is no Cin for the LSB, it is zero.  My alternate method does not do the "B+1" in the parentheses, I just put ~B.  Then I add the 1 by setting the carry to a 1.  You didn't say what you are setting Cin to.

Comment: I've modified my description, have a look at that.

Comment: i've also editted my question now. as this is my leftover problem to be fixed! I really appreciate all your help and responses so far Kevin! and also just saw your edit. I've used ~B+1b'1 to add in the 1bit for 2's complement